# how to use \polyhornerscheme command

Tags: polynom

How to use `\polyhornerscheme` command to divide the polynomial `f(x)=2x^4-3x^3+4x^2-5x+ 6` by `(x-2)(x+5)`?
I used this one

```
\begin{document}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{polynom}

    \polyhornerscheme[x=2]{2x^4-3x^3+4x^2-5x+ 6}

\end{document}
```

but I want to get the division by `x=2` and then divide the result by `x=-5`.
to get [image]

Comment: Hi, welcome. To format code as code, you can select it and hit Ctrl+K (or click the button marked `{}`). This will place inline code between two backticks (`\``), or indent blocks by four spaces. Regarding the math expressions, MathJax isn't enabled on this site, so they won't be rendered nicely.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.